# Short story where the protagonist is unknowingly the demon Beelzebub.

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in the 80s (as in a read it in the 80s, not that it was written in the 80s) about a protagonist that was bothered by flies, and was unknowingly the demon Beelzebub.  Any ideas?

Comment: :) If you can take a look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and edit the answers to question into your question, we'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That would be [Flies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flies_(Asimov_short_story)), by Isaac Asimov.  Available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v004n06_1953-06/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v004n06_1953-06#page/n17/mode/2up).

It wasn't the protagonist who was bothered by flies, as it happens, but one of his old friends.  The story was set at a college reunion.

> Winthrop would never know.  Polen was sure of that.  He wondered if Casey knew.  It would be the supreme joke if Casey did not.
>
> He *had* run Casey's flies, of course, not that once alone, but many times.  Always the same answer!  Always the same unpublishable answer.
>
> With a cold shiver he could not quite control, Polen was suddenly conscious of a single fly loose in the room, veering aimlessly for a moment, then beating strongly and reverently toward Beezlebub.

Comment: Thank you!  I was getting to the point where I thought I dreamed this story.

Comment: I like how the name of the story is literally the first thing mentioned in the question. Haha.

Comment: Just to note, the quote here is correct in using "run Casey's flies" - it's not a typo for "run Casey's *files*", the way my mind read it at first.  For context, it's short for "*run experiments on* Casey's flies".